# How to expand text using scraper

Tags: java, web-scraping

I need to create a Java application (is partly created) which needs to scrap all the reviews from tripadvisor webpage like this: 
http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187323-d233869-Reviews-or10-Hotel_Delta-Berlin.html

I'm very new with with web-harverst so now I see a problem with this not-expanded text. To see the full version of reviews one needs to click "More"-link which looks like:

```
<span class="taLnk hvrIE6 tr162902990 moreLink ulBlueLinks" onclick="ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(2247);ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.expandReviews',event,this,'review_162902990', '1', 2247)">    More </span>
```

So it runs a script and probably asks a database.
My question is: is there any possibility to simulate this "More"-clicking action in Java? Or another way to get the full texts? Which library could help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which scraper are you using? Jsoup?

Comment: I try to use Jsoup. But I can change, if it cannot simulate "More"-clicking.

Comment: Jsoup is a parser. I dont think it can click Javascript buttons. You can use HtmlUnit for that http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Actually I understand the nature of Jsoup. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HtmlUnit really can do it. But I still have difficulties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203701/htmlunit-to-expand-reviews